# What are Potential Causes of Windows to Flash Orange at Startup

Tags: windows, windbg

On a Windows 7 PosReady operating system, observe an orange flash at startup. It happens very quickly, it is almost unnoticeable. To capture it I launched in Hyper-V and set CPU to max use 1% to slow down boot process. A google search of this experience returns many users encountering this but have not found any definitive definition.

Screen capture from Virtual machine:

[image: Orange Screen from Capture]

As it was slow enough I could now break into Kernel debugger while these orange screen was still being displayed.

This is what is running at time:

[image: Process running at time]

The WinLogon/WinInit stacks at time. SWIN is McAfee Solidcore agent.

```
PROCESS 86c5b7f0  SessionId: 1  Cid: 02c4    Peb: 7ffd8000  ParentCid: 028c
    DirBase: f6ea50e0  ObjectTable: a1cd5a88  HandleCount:   0.
    Image: winlogon.exe
    VadRoot 85cca438 Vads 8 Clone 0 Private 9. Modified 0. Locked 0.
    DeviceMap 00000000
    Token                             a1cd69a8
    ElapsedTime                       00:00:06.609
    UserTime                          00:00:00.000
    KernelTime                        00:00:00.000
    QuotaPoolUsage[PagedPool]         7636
    QuotaPoolUsage[NonPagedPool]      480
    Working Set Sizes (now,min,max)  (18, 50, 345) (72KB, 200KB, 1380KB)
    PeakWorkingSetSize                19
    VirtualSize                       2 Mb
    PeakVirtualSize                   2 Mb
    PageFaultCount                    15
    MemoryPriority                    BACKGROUND
    BasePriority                      8
    CommitCharge                      60

        THREAD 86e9e378  Cid 02c4.02c8  Teb: 7ffdf000 Win32Thread: 00000000 RUNNING on processor 0
        IRP List:
            86feea50: (0006,02d4) Flags: 00000884  Mdl: 00000000
        Not impersonating
        Owning Process            86c5b7f0       Image:         winlogon.exe
        Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
        Wait Start TickCount      37023          Ticks: 13 (0:00:00:00.203)
        Context Switch Count      6              IdealProcessor: 0             
        UserTime                  00:00:00.000
        KernelTime                00:00:00.093
        Win32 Start Address 0x006412bf
        Stack Init 91407ed0 Current 914074f0 Base 91408000 Limit 91405000 Call 00000000
        Priority 8 BasePriority 8 PriorityDecrement 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
        ChildEBP RetAddr  
        91407400 828c99d0 nt!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction (FPO: [1,0,0])
        91407408 828c99a2 nt!KdCheckForDebugBreak+0x22 (FPO: [0,0,0])
        91407438 828c9830 nt!KeUpdateRunTime+0x164
        91407490 828c9033 nt!KeUpdateSystemTime+0x613
        91407490 82971605 nt!KeUpdateSystemTimeAssist+0x13 (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ 914074a4)
        91407560 8d6249d0 nt!ExAllocatePoolWithTag+0x5fb
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
        91407574 8d6d9dbf swin+0x39d0
        91407590 8d6d9ed6 swin+0xb8dbf
        914075a8 8d67cb90 swin+0xb8ed6
        914075f4 8d673d95 swin+0x5bb90
        91407614 8d68db07 swin+0x52d95
        914076dc 8d68e114 swin+0x6cb07
        9140770c 8d64c80a swin+0x6d114
        9140772c 8d648c4f swin+0x2b80a
        9140775c 8d64a9ca swin+0x27c4f
        9140778c 8d64b1c2 swin+0x299ca
        914077c0 8d64482f swin+0x2a1c2
        914077dc 8d7d4e09 swin+0x2382f
        91407820 82885129 swin+0x1b3e09
        91407838 82a99539 nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
        91407918 82a788fe nt!IopParseDevice+0xf08
        91407994 82a88eb0 nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x510
        914079f4 82a7f7db nt!ObOpenObjectByName+0x165
        91407a70 82a85b33 nt!IopCreateFile+0x673
        91407ab8 82acfea3 nt!NtOpenFile+0x2a
        91407b38 82aae8e9 nt!PfSnGetPrefetchInstructions+0xab
        91407bc8 82ac67bd nt!PfSnBeginAppLaunch+0x303
        91407bd8 82aac652 nt!PfProcessCreateNotification+0x65
        91407c20 828ffa59 nt!PspUserThreadStartup+0x113
        00000000 00000000 nt!KiThreadStartup+0x19

PROCESS 85ccad28  SessionId: 0  Cid: 02cc    Peb: 7ffd3000  ParentCid: 025c
    DirBase: f6ea5100  ObjectTable: 9f20f820  HandleCount:   0.
    Image: wininit.exe
    VadRoot 86c4c568 Vads 8 Clone 0 Private 10. Modified 0. Locked 0.
    DeviceMap 00000000
    Token                             9f24c770
    ElapsedTime                       00:00:01.109
    UserTime                          00:00:00.000
    KernelTime                        00:00:00.000
    QuotaPoolUsage[PagedPool]         7236
    QuotaPoolUsage[NonPagedPool]      480
    Working Set Sizes (now,min,max)  (19, 50, 345) (76KB, 200KB, 1380KB)
    PeakWorkingSetSize                20
    VirtualSize                       1 Mb
    PeakVirtualSize                   1 Mb
    PageFaultCount                    16
    MemoryPriority                    BACKGROUND
    BasePriority                      8
    CommitCharge                      59

        THREAD 8707f560  Cid 02cc.02d0  Teb: 7ffdf000 Win32Thread: 00000000 READY on processor 0
        IRP List:
            88b77008: (0006,02d4) Flags: 00060043  Mdl: 9a1f0900
            87eda788: (0006,02d4) Flags: 00000884  Mdl: 00000000
        Not impersonating
        Owning Process            85ccad28       Image:         wininit.exe
        Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
        Wait Start TickCount      37032          Ticks: 4 (0:00:00:00.062)
        Context Switch Count      4              IdealProcessor: 0             
        UserTime                  00:00:00.000
        KernelTime                00:00:00.140
        Win32 Start Address 0x00ea4dc8
        Stack Init 8f8f0ed0 Current 8f8f02e8 Base 8f8f1000 Limit 8f8ee000 Call 00000b2c
        Priority 8 BasePriority 8 PriorityDecrement 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5

        ChildEBP RetAddr  
        8f8f0300 828ccf6d nt!KiSwapContext+0x26 (FPO: [Uses EBP] [0,0,4])
        8f8f0338 828cbdc7 nt!KiSwapThread+0x266
        8f8f0360 828c560f nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1df
        8f8f03dc 8d825c77 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x393
        8f8f03fc 8d82674a Ntfs!NtfsWaitOnIo+0x1c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f051c 8d82a765 Ntfs!NtfsNonCachedIo+0x456 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f05f0 8d82bdc5 Ntfs!NtfsCommonRead+0x1148 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0728 82885129 Ntfs!NtfsFsdRead+0x279 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0740 8d49e20c nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
        8f8f0764 8d49e3cb FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x2aa (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f079c 82885129 FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0xc5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f07b4 8d64483e nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
        8f8f07c8 8d66153f swin+0x2383e
        8f8f0808 82885129 swin+0x4053f
        8f8f0820 82913ddf nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
        8f8f083c 828f5deb nt!IoPageRead+0x1f5
        8f8f08a4 828df2cc nt!MiIssueHardFault+0x28c
        8f8f0924 8288ef98 nt!MmAccessFault+0x29fc
        8f8f0924 82a84de6 nt!KiTrap0E+0xdc (FPO: [0,0] TrapFrame @ 8f8f093c)
        8f8f09f0 8d8c1305 nt!CcMapData+0xae
        8f8f0a18 8d8c6931 Ntfs!NtfsMapStream+0x4a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0a48 8d8b2792 Ntfs!ReadIndexBuffer+0xdd (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0a78 8d8bd050 Ntfs!FindFirstIndexEntry+0x1fa (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0ac4 8d8c543b Ntfs!NtfsFindIndexEntry+0x48 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0af8 8d8ad6bb Ntfs!NtfsLookupEntry+0xa4 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0bdc 8d8311b6 Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+0x98a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0c1c 828ce08a Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreateCallout+0x20 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        8f8f0c1c 828ce181 nt!KiSwapKernelStackAndExit+0x15a (FPO: [0,0] TrapFrame @ 8f8f0c34)
        9140b4fc 828d7d7f nt!KiSwitchKernelStackAndCallout+0x31
        9140b570 8d8310ec nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx+0x29d
        9140b5a8 8d8c2a6a Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreateOnNewStack+0x39 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        9140b6a4 82885129 Ntfs!NtfsFsdCreate+0x1f8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        9140b6bc 8d49e20c nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
        9140b6e0 8d4b18c9 FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x2aa (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        9140b72c 82885129 FLTMGR!FltpCreate+0x2db (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
        9140b744 8d664745 nt!IofCallDriver+0x63
        9140b758 8d64aa53 swin+0x43745
        9140b78c 8d64b1c2 swin+0x29a53
        9140b7c0 8d64482f swin+0x2a1c2
        9140b7dc 8d7d4e09 swin+0x2382f
```